# How to fix MongoDB Data API error: "Header missing: please add content-type: application/json or application/ejson to specify payload data types"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas, zoho, zoho-deluge

I was attempting to insert a document into MongoDB Atlas, via the Data API.

However, the API kept returning the following error:

> Header missing: please add content-type: application/json or application/ejson to specify payload data types.

This was unexpected. As you can see in the deluge script below, the "Content-Type" was specified in the header:

**Original Code**

```
// POST to MongoDB Data API 
headers = Map();
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.put("api-key", "API-KEY");
headers.put("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "*");

data = Map();
data.put("dataSource", "cluster");
data.put("database", "database");
data.put("collection", "names");

document = Map();
document.put("full_name", "Ari Adar");
data.put("document", document);

response = invokeurl
[
    url: "https://ap-southeast-2.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-***/endpoint/data/v1/action/insertOne"
    type: POST
    parameters: data.toString()
    headers: headers
];

alert response;
```

After some debugging, I eventually discovered that the error response from the Data API is inaccurate.

The solution is the script must convert the data map to a JSON string before passing it to the invokeURL function.

**Working Code**

```
// POST to MongoDB Data API 
headers = Map();
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.put("api-key", "API-KEY");
headers.put("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "*");

data = Map();
data.put("dataSource", "cluster");
data.put("database", "database");
data.put("collection", "names");

document = Map();
document.put("full_name", "Ari Adar");
data.put("document", document);

// Stringify the data map 
data_string = data.toString();

response = invokeurl
[
    url: "https://ap-southeast-2.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-***/endpoint/data/v1/action/insertOne"
    type: POST
    parameters: data_string
    headers: headers
];

alert response;
```

I hope this helps anyone else encountering the same error message. It would be great if MongoDB could update it.

Answer (score 0):

Very good question. I managed to find also a thread on mongoapi website about it under this link:

[Unable to POST, strange response](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/unable-to-post-strange-response/188801/4).

So based on that I managed to fix it by changing following line in my http client:

```
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody reqBody = RequestBody.create(body, mediaType);
```

And change those two into the following line:

```
RequestBody reqBody = RequestBody.create(body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

But agree that the error log in my NetBeans seemed very strange:

```
Header missing: please add content-type: application/json or application/ejson to specify payload data types
```